# Failed to run app:Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

added a photo, can any one help me? ill post anything i can.
there is no " ERRORS " but it crash it selfs..

blue= my 24 line.
red= my Exception[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPEOY.png)

activity_main_appbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

       <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>



        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:name="com.example.dannygavrilov.materialtest.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.dannygavrilov.materialtest.MainActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="512dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment

        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.dannygavrilov.materialtest.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.dannygavrilov.materialtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You just hit " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.navigate) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SubActivity1.class));
        }

        if (id == R.id.likebutton) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SubActivity2.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

NavigationDrawerFragment:

```
package com.example.dannygavrilov.materialtest;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testpref";
    public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "user_learned_drawer";
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private DannyAdapter adapter;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private View containerView;
    private boolean isDrawerOpened=false;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        adapter =new DannyAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return layout;
    }

    public static List<Information> getData() {
        List<Information> data=new ArrayList<>();
        int[] icons = {R.drawable.ic_launcher1, R.drawable.ic_launcher2, R.drawable.ic_launcher3, R.drawable.ic_launcher4};
        String[] titles = {"Delete", "Trash", "New message", "Contact"};
        for (int i=0;i< titles.length && i < icons.length; i++)
        {
            Information current =new Information();
            current.iconId=icons[i];
            current.title=titles[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;

    }

    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    saveToPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, mUserLearnedDrawer + "");
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                if (slideOffset < 0.5) {
                    toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset);
                }
            }
        };
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);

        }
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();

            }
        });
    }

    public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
10-31 13:34:15.365  17440-17440/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dannygavrilov.materialtest, PID: 17440
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dannygavrilov.materialtest/com.example.dannygavrilov.materialtest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.dannygavrilov.materialtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:464)
            at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6383)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1837)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1749)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:768)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at com.example.dannygavrilov.materialtest.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:57)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:985)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1277)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2232)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:278)
            at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:78)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.dannygavrilov.materialtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/miWbx.png

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Added 2 xml files, and 2 classes

Comment: Please post the **entire** stack trace, as **text**, as an edit to your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare i uploaded all the package, and classes and everything to this link, i hope you will find the problem thank you very much! http://www.filedropper.com/materialtest2 and edited in text/code in my question post full exception

Comment: Your crash is from `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/18741485/115145 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/17390355/115145 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/26173031/115145 for some ideas

Comment: @CommonsWare First of all, Thank you for trying to help me , what you sent me I checked the links , but unfortunately I have trouble finding the problem would be very happy if I could for the purpose of contacting you via Skype , or email, and you can help me or take the whole package I uploaded and analyze it
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

first clean the project and then again build it.if it doesn't work,uninstall android v4 library and install it again.Hope it works.

Comment: Can you post the instructions to do it, im new on studio android.